# Render an ActiveReccord:relationship with specific cat value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

My title is not really clear, I don't know how to formulate it, if you have suggestions, I can edit it.

I would like to render all the missions form my user_facturation. But I don't know how to do it with current db structure.

My relations :

```
mission has_many :mission_facturations
mission_facturation belongs_to :mission
```

Mission_facturation can be linked with many element facturation (user, partner, etc ...). So to save this relation I'm saving a fact_cat and a fact_id column. (A little bit has polymorphic relations)

Example, if I want to link my mission_facturation with the first user_facturation, I reccord :

```
mission_facturation.update(fact_cat: 8, fact_id: UserFacturation.first.id)
```

Now, I would like to access to all the missions directly from my user_facturation model. Initially, I was using that method into the model user_facturation.rb

```
def missions
  MissionFacturation.where(fact_cat: 8, fact_id: self.id).where.not(mission_id: nil).map(&:mission)
end
```

But this is not rendering an ActiveReccord::Relation, so when I use it for a loop, it's not working well

Do you have any solutions to render a collection of missions into my user_facturation model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the query with the Mission model, something like this:

```
Mission.joins(:mission_facturations).where(mission_facturations: {fact_cat: 8, fact_id: self.id)
```

Or you can even set a relationship on the User class so AR handles the joins for you:

```
has_many :mission_facturations, -> { where(fact_cat: 8) }, :foreign_key => "fact_id"
has_many :missions, through: :mission_facturations
```

Comment: Hi @arieljud, thanks for your answer, it's exactly what I'm looking for !! The first solution is working well ! But the second looks strongest. The only thing is that is not working because the id is not specified on the first line. I think the first should look something like this : has_many :mission_facturations, -> { where(fact_cat: 8, fact_id: self.id) }. But obviously is not the good syntax. Do you have an idea for the response ?